# Consuming WCF Service with Objective C Issue

Tags: c#, ios, wcf

I'm trying to consume a wcf service that I have published in iis on my local computer. The WCF service is inside my router so I'm only able to access the service outside of the router. (I do this by turning wifi off on my phone and I'm able to reach the service). I'm trying to execute a GET method.

The server side WCF code looks like this:

//Service1.svc.cs

```
public string GetUsers()
        {
            var userController = new UserController();

            string returnString = userController.GetAllUsers();

            return returnString;
        }
```

//IService.cs

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetUsers")]
        string GetUsers();
```

//Iphone Client

```
- (IBAction)btnSendRequest:(id)sender
{
    NSString *restCallString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"publicIP/MyService/Service1.svc/GetUsers"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:restCallString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;


    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

}
```

Now if I change the restCallString to something like http://www.apple.com then my *result variable will get data back. I am debugging this in Xcode on my actual device with the wifi turned off on my device. In theory it should behave just as it does when I view the service method in the browser on my phone but it is not working. The *result variable always returns nil when trying to reach my service. If anyone has tips or advice I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have Chrome on IOS, perhaps you can add the Postman extension and test your ability to successfully contact the WCF service from the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to consider using this, I think the WCF service may be incorrectly configured.

You would need to mark a response Format in your Service as well as configure Web Binding.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: Hi Dane, I tried adding the Response type as JSON like in the link above. My web.config looked a little different then what was in the article. However, I did an NSLog on the *error message localized description coming back after the respond. It returns an "unsupported URL" status. If I find a solution for this I will post it here.

Comment: Solved it, what worked for me was adding http:// right before publicIP in my url and it worked perfectly.